# How to show urgent upgrades in synaptic

Tags: upgrade, synaptic

At times, I would like to use Synaptic to find only those upgradable packages that have high urgency upgrades available. Is there a way to define a filter that does this?

Example: today I upgraded `bash` and didn't have time to upgrade everything else, but still I figured I could upgrade other vulnerable packages at the same time, only I couldn't find a list of those.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `apt-get` easily .

First create a source list which contain only security repo.

```
grep security /etc/apt/sources.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.seurity.list
```

Now upgrade your system using this list

```
apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list
```

I am not 100% sure about synaptic, but synaptic has a section of **security repository**  when **origin** option is selected. It may be used to select security updates.[image]

Comment: The Synaptic solution is not perfect: it seems like it selects all packages that have ever had a high urgency upgrade. But it's close enough for my purpose. Thanks!